# Can't you use managed metadata navigation in communication sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, metadata-navigation

I just noticed that although you don't have the option from the site settings you can open the navigation settings with the url and you can still set the navigation as managed metadata but it does not seem to work on communication sites.

I could not find anything confirming that but is that a thing? does anyone know any source with that info and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a modern Communication site you're much better off using the Hub navigation instead of the managed metadata navigation. The MMD navigation has been prone to all kind of problems, but its biggest flaw is that it can only be applied to ONE site collection.

So, you'd need to create multiple duplicates of the MMD navigation term sets, one for each site collection (each modern site is a site collection). And that is where the problems begin, since the inheritance of MMD navigation doesn't work properly for this purpose.

This is probably the reason that MMD Navigation is not displaying on modern sites: It's more headache to get it to work than it's worth.

Create the navigation in a hub site instead and join the Communication site to that hub.

There may be reasons why the legacy MMD Navigation is still showing as an option in the backend, but the most likely reason is probably because the cleanup would take away resources from the projects that put out new functionality. I'd rather have new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, managed metadata navigation cannot be used in the SharePoint communication sites. Because Publishing feature cannot be activated in the communication sites.